# How to compare two graphs of companies data

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, data

I can plot a graph for one company at a time. For example :

```
    DateListPlot[Entity["Company", "NVIDIACorporation::7ymsk"][EntityProperty["Company","GrossProfit", {"TimeSeriesType" -> #, "Date" -> All}]], ImageSize -> 200, PlotLabel -> #, PlotTheme -> "Business"] & /@ {"Annual", "Quarterly", "TTM"}
```

How could I compare two "TTM" values of this company and another company on a graph. I tried various things, but I still can't figure it out.

EDIT: I tried to somehow move the pure function, so that it could compare two companies. It turns out I only got to compare two properties of the same company. CODE:

```
DateListPlot[[EntityProperty["Company","GrossProfit",{"TimeSeriesType"->#,"Date"->All}]]&/@{"TTM", "Annual"},ImageSize->200,PlotLabel-> "Graph",PlotTheme->"Business"]
```

Comment: _I tried various things_ - what did you try? Please put the code in your post. Did you try `Show` or `DateListPlot[{company1, company2},...]` ?

Comment: @flinty I tried DateListPlot, but I cannot choose the date or property to display.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by: "How could I compare two "TTM" values of this company and another company on a graph".  `TTM` is a time series. How can you compare `TTM` of the same company? To compare `TTM ` of different companies, do you mean 2 series in the same plot or their ratio?

Comment: @DanielHuber I mean two series of "TTM" of different companies on the same plot yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include a list of time series as first argument of `DateListPlot` you will get a plot with multiple curves.

Here is an example where I plot "TTM" and "Quarterly" of the given company in the same plot. For clarity, I first create the time series separately and subsequently feed them to `DateListPlot`:

```
ds1 = Entity["Company", "NVIDIACorporation::7ymsk"][
   EntityProperty["Company", 
    "GrossProfit", {"TimeSeriesType" -> "TTM", "Date" -> All}]];
ds2 = Entity["Company", "NVIDIACorporation::7ymsk"][
   EntityProperty["Company", 
    "GrossProfit", {"TimeSeriesType" -> "Quarterly", "Date" -> All}]];
DateListPlot[{ds1, ds2}]
```

[image]

If we want to restrict the dates to plot, we can do so e.g. by:

```
DateListPlot[{ds1, ds2},PlotRange -> {{{2005, 1, 1}, {2020, 1, 1}}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you maybe know how to set "Date" to be from a certain point onward ?

Comment: A added an example to my answer.